# How to compare two datetime variables correctly?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to compare two datetime variables to detect the current time is in weekend time or not.

My code is here:

```
def is_weekend_off(weekend_table, trading_timezone):
    now_trading_timezone = datetime.now(tz=trading_timezone)
    is_weekend = False
    for it in weekend_table:
        condition1 = it[0] <= now_trading_timezone
        condition2 = now_trading_timezone < it[1]
        condition3 = condition1 and condition2
        print('now = ' + str(now_trading_timezone))
        print('it[0] = ' + str(it[0]))
        print('it[1] = ' + str(it[1]))
        print('condition1 = ' + str(condition1))
        print('condition2 = ' + str(condition2))
        time.sleep(60)
        if condition3:
            tmp = True
        else:
            tmp = False
        is_weekend = is_weekend or tmp
    return is_weekend
```

and the result is here:

```
now = 2018-09-10 21:50:59.001475-05:00
it[0] = 2018-09-10 21:00:00-05:51
it[1] = 2018-09-10 22:00:00-05:51
condition1 = False
condition2 = True
```

As I know, condition1 should be True, not False.  How do I correct this result?

Comment: Why not just use something like ` date.weekday(datetime.now(tz=trading_timezone)) == 5 or date.weekday(datetime.now(tz=trading_timezone)) == 6`.

Comment: Timezone `-05:51` is likely an error. Such a timezone does not exist in reality. The code that produces the datetime value with it likely contains a problem.

Comment: You may consider to use a library, such as `arrow`, that makes moving an instant of time between different timezones easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `it[0]` has a timezone of `-05:51`, so when `now_trading_timezone`, whose timezone is `-05:00`, is compared to `it[0]`, `now_trading_timezone` becomes effectively `2018-09-10 21:50:59.001475` minus `51` minutes, equaling `20:59:59.001475-05:51`, which is less than `it[0]`'s `2018-09-10 21:00:00-05:51`, resulting in `False` for the condition `it[0] <= now_trading_timezone`.

To correct `it[0]`'s timezone with `now_trading_timezone`'s, you can use the `datetime.replace` method:

```
it[0] = it[0].replace(tzinfo=now_trading_timezone.tzinfo)
```

Comment: Now I know where the problem is.  How do I correct the time from -05:51to -05:00?

Comment: I found there is some problem on setting timezone in datetime attribute, like:

`datetime(year=2018, month=9, day=11, hour=1, minute=15, second=0, tzinfo=trading_timezone)`

I use `localize()` to set the timezone instead and the result is correct:
`trading_timezone.localize(datetime(year=2018, month=9, day=11, hour=1, minute=15, second=0))`